# Qemu, div by zero, mxcsr register

Tags: android, c, floating-point, qemu, kvm

I got an interesting situation with the following code:

```
    static void DivideByZero() {
      // volatile to prevent compiler optimizations.
      volatile float zero = 0.0f;
      volatile float result __attribute__((unused)) = 123.0f / zero;
    }
  DivideByZero();
  int raised = fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_OVERFLOW);
  ASSERT_TRUE((raised & FE_DIVBYZERO) != 0);
```

When I run my qemu device with `KVM` support I got the following results:

> ```
>  FE_DIVBYZERO !=0; //and it's ok
> ```

But when I run the same source without `KVM` support:

> ```
>  FE_DIVBYZERO ==0; //and it's not ok
> ```

As I understand this situation, it happens, because in `mxcsr` the register bit (div by zero) is not set. But I don't understand why this bit is not set.
Any ideas?

**UPDATE**  :
Same situation has happend for `android` emulator based on qemu.

```
emulator -avd test -qemu
```

return: FE_DIVBYZERO !=0;

```
emulator -avd test -qemu -disable-kvm
```

return: FE_DIVBYZERO ==0;

Comment: MXCSR is in play when your code uses SSE instructions. Are you sure it's SSE and not FPU instructions in your program?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Yes, i'm shure, only KVM on/off affect here, probably KVM affect on SSE/FPU...

Comment: can you give more information about host / guest / qemu options used... ( 32bits/64bits ... )

Comment: Linux on x86 platform 64 bit

Comment: Which case is failing, with or without KVM?  I see a typo in the question - "witout" KVM and "without" KVM - so it isn't clear which case is ok and which is failing.

Comment: @amdn I have updated description. Wrong situation without KVM support

Comment: @Pepelac alright, clearly then there is a bug in QEMU's emulation of the SSE divide instruction for a scalar in single precision (DIVSS).  I've downloaded the QEMU source from git (http://wiki.qemu.org/Download) but it will take more time than I have now to figure it out... I suggest you file a bug report to QEMU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MXCSR` register is described in the 
[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/253665.pdf)

On modern x86 processors the compiler maps floating point operations as `scalar` SIMD, using the same resources that `vector (SSE)` instructions use.

The `MXCSR` register controls the operation of both `scalar` and `vector (SSE)` floating point instructions.  I've included the relevant section describing the MXCSR below.  `MXCSR[9]` is the Divide-by-Zero Mask, if cleared (0) then the CPU will raise an exception when Divide by Zero is detected.  When you are running in a virtual machine exceptions are "virtualized", they are handled by a "hypervisor", [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) in your case.  The hypervisor then decides whether to reflect the exception back to the guest virtual machine.  My theory is that the Divide-by-Zero Mask is cleared, the exception is raised, KVM and/or QEMU is clearing the flag that indicates a divide by zero exception happened `MXCSR[2]` and resumes your virtual machine.  This is therefore likely a bug in KVM/QEMU.

You could issue [**fegetexcept()**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fegetexcept) before the `DivideByZero()` to find out if the Divide-By-Zero exception is masked (1) or not (0).  If it is not masked then you could use [**fedisableexcept()**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fedisableexcept) to mask it.

[image: MXCSR Control/Status Register]

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I got same result by fegetexcept()  for KVM and non KVM emulator.
results is 0;
fedisableexcept also didn't help.
Do you have more ideas?

Comment: You are welcome.  Did you call fedisableexcept with FE_DIVBYZERO as the parameter, like this: `fedisableexcept ( FE_DIVBYZERO )` ?

Comment: Yes. I use fedisableexcept with FE_DIVBYZERO, also just with value I got same result.

Comment: As far as I know store/load of `MXCSR` does not cause a "VM exit" - in other words, the hypervisor cannot "hook" a store/load of the MXCSR - if you mask the divide by zero exception then the hypervisor won't get control on the exception either.  I'm at a loss to explain what is happening.  I'll give it more thought.

Comment: The default MXCSR state is for FP exceptions to be masked, and all mainstream OSes start fresh processes this way.  If you unmask an FP exception and cause one to be raised, OSes like Linux will deliver a SIGFPE (POSIX signal) to your process.  If you haven't installed a handler for it, your process will exit.

Answer (score 2):

When QEMU works as a software emulation.

### From http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-tech.html#intro_005fx86_005femulation.

2.8 Exception support

longjmp() is used when an exception such as division by zero is encountered.

The host SIGSEGV and SIGBUS signal handlers are used to get invalid memory accesses. The simulated program counter is found by retranslating the corresponding basic block and by looking where the host program counter was at the exception point.

### The virtual CPU cannot retrieve the exact EFLAGS register because in some cases it is not computed because of condition code optimisations. It is not a big concern because the emulated code can still be restarted in any cases.

Looks like the FPU state is lost too and the bits indicating what is the FPU exception - division by zero/invalid arguments in your case  are lost. And QEMU could not properly emulate fetestexcept. Hence the result.

When QEMU works using hardware virtualization - KVM, the floating point exceptions are handled properly - so the test is correct.

-- edit:
Other posibility is that the exceptions mode is initialized differently:
You may try to add that to enable div by zero exception.
feenableexcept (FE_INVALID | FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_OVERFLOW);

Comment: We have volatitle for avoiding any optimizations

Comment: You have volatile in the code that runs in an emulation - sw or hw. That can not affect the behavior of the emulator itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the logic, but QEMU is software implementation and KVM is hardware support. So may be in software implementation the bit is not set because of floating point mis-calculation or storing floating point value..